# How to deal with alias registers in data-flow analysis using SSA form? (e.g. EAX/AX/AH/AL in x86)

Tags: compiler-construction, x86, alias, dataflow, ssa

For exmaple:

How to represent the following x86 in [SSA form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form):

```
xor  eax, eax
inc  ax
```

By introducing some pseudo functions, I come up with:

```
eax@1 = eax@0 ^ eax@0
ax@1 = LOWORD(eax@1)
al@1 = LOBYTE(ax@1)
ah@1 = HIBYTE(ax@1)
hax@1 = HIWORD(eax@1)

ax@2 = ax@1 + 1
eax@2 = MAKEDWORD(ax@2, HIWORD(eax@1))
al@2 = LOBYTE(ax@2)
ah@2 = HIBYTE(ax@2)
```

But I think it's too much verbose

Comment: What do you mean by "SSA form"?

Comment: @Eli Bendersky: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form

Comment: Don't have any suggestions on simplifying this, but I am curious as to where this is being used. Are you trying to optimize / translate an existing compiled application?

***** Looking at the example above, wouldn't you need to keep eax, ax, al and ah synchronized at every step. For example, what if the next instructions is a conditional branch where one path used ax and the other uses eax? You would then need to be even more verbose to update all the versions of this register updated !

Comment: @Gautham Ganapathy: I'm decompiling (heavily obfuscated) binary. For branches, SSA introduced the phi function, see wiki for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your notation:

1. eax@0 = ... whatever it was before here ...
2. eax@1 = 0
3. ax@2 = ax@1 + 1

Because eax contains ax, there's an implicit step in between 2 and 3

1. eax@0 = ...
2. eax@1 = 0
3. ax@1  = 0 (because ax cannot be non-zero if eax is zero)
4. ax@2  = ax@1 + 1

Step 2 because any number xor'ed with itself is 0... eax@0 is dead at that point, and thus eax@1 can be renamed (using ebx as renaming so it's readable; obviously you would use a virtual register, not a real one):

1. --- deleted, eax no longer relevant
2. ebx@0 = 0
3. bx@0  = 0
4. bx@1 = bx@0 + 1

You could then note that because step 3 is a constant function, so is step 4 (adding a constant to a constant) and compress the two together (i.e. constant folding)

1. -- deleted, eax no longer relevant
2. ebx@0 = 0
3. bx@0  = 1

If the upper 16 bits of ebx don't dominate anything below this, you could also delete step 2.

Comment: Yeah you right. I'm trying to avoid the verbose, but the verbose may be the feature of SSA.